# Tabbar and navbar don't work with UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

Tags: c#, ios, animation, xamarin

So I want to transition from my loading screen viewcontroller to the main viewcontroller of my app. I do this using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` because it works better than the `transitionFromView:` that I had before.

But it still isn't perfect. I have a bar on the top of my view, which you can see at the top ([A bit like this](https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers)) and a tabbar on the bottom of my view.

Now the view it animates to is like this:

[image]

As you can see the tabbar and the navigationbar are too high, which is immediately fixed in the next frame. This causes the app to flicker. I don't want this. What am I doing wrong? If it's not something I am doing wrong, how can I fix it? (I already tried adding it to a window that is the correct size, but it does not work)

This is my code for the transition (it's Xamarin, but you should be able to understand the gist of it):

```
// Grab the from and to view controllers from the context
var fromViewController = transitionContext.GetViewControllerForKey(UITransitionContext.FromViewControllerKey);
var toViewController = transitionContext.GetViewControllerForKey(UITransitionContext.ToViewControllerKey);

toViewController.WillMoveToParentViewController(fromViewController);
fromViewController.View.InsertSubview(toViewController.View, 0);
toViewController.View.LayoutIfNeeded();
toViewController.View.RemoveFromSuperview();

fromViewController.View.UserInteractionEnabled = false;

transitionContext.ContainerView.AddSubview(fromViewController.View);
transitionContext.ContainerView.AddSubview(toViewController.View);

toViewController.View.Alpha = 0;

UIView.Animate(TransitionDuration(transitionContext), () => {
    toViewController.View.Alpha = 1;
}, () => {
    transitionContext.CompleteTransition(true);
    fromViewController.Dispose();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I was doing this:

```
UIView.Animate(TransitionDuration(transitionContext), () => {
    toViewController.View.Alpha = 1;
}, () => {
    transitionContext.CompleteTransition(true);
    fromViewController.Dispose();
});
```

When I should have done this:

```
PresentViewController(_controller, true, null);
```

The animation does not use the `transitioningDelegate`, so I was not actually using it...